# Best database design approach for a checklist application with high data volume

Tags: database, database-design

For our system, a checklist is defined as a group of items. Every item has two possible states: it is either OK or Not OK (NOK). When filling a checklist in our app, if the user marks an item as NOK, a list of possible problems is showed. The user then can select one or more problems that are related with the current checklist item. We consider an item as OK when the user has not selected any NOK option.

Item Example:
An item example would be: **Icecream**
If the user marks this item as NOK, the list of possible options could be:

- Melted
- Bad Taste
- ...

The database for this system has the following tables:

`CHECKLIST_TEMPLATE:`

All templates of possible checklists that an user can answer is saved in that table. The user is free to create or edit as many templates as he wants.

`CHECKLIST_ITEMS:`

Here we associate what items belongs to what template. An item can only belong to one template but a template can have many items.

`CHECKLIST_ITEMS_NOK_OPTIONS:`

In this table we associate NOK options with a checklist item. A NOK option can only belong to one item but an item can have many NOK options.

These are the basic tables to put the checklist running. We have another set of tables to save checklists answered by users:

`CHECKLIST:`

That table contains: what user answered, what template and when. Every entry in this table has its own unique ID.

`CHECKLIST_ANSWERS:`

In this table we associate a Checklist ID (from the `CHECKLIST` table) with a NOK option. If an item has 5 NOK options, we save in this table five entries, informing if the user selected or not this NOK option when answering the checklist (further down you will understand why we use this approach).

Now to the problem:

A checklist with 30 items, every item with 3 NOK options will add to the `CHECKLIST_ANSWERS` table 90 lines. This table is currently growing 100k lines per day and we are concerned with the table size. This table tends to grow even faster with time. So, next month might be 120k lines per day, the other 150k lines per day (to the end of 2018 we estimate this table would be growing 400k lines per day and in the middle of 2019, 2kk lines per day)...

We can't delete old checklists because they are used to generate some reports to our clients.

Recreating answered checklists

> (further down you will understand why we use this approach)

We choose to save every NOK option because the user is able to edit a template. So, he is able to change an item description, for instance. This is a dangerous feature (that is also necessary) because if the user changes the *meaning* of an item, the already answered checklists might be compromised. To overcome this problem and ensure the checklists integrity, when the user edits an item, we check in the back-end to detect if the meaning of the item has changed. If that happens, the current item is inactivated (with all its options) and another item is automatically created and associated with the template. This ensures that old checklists are associate with the old item and the new ones will be associated with the new item.

The same logic happens if the user edits a NOK option as well.

Because of that, we need to know, for every checklist answered by an user, what items were included in the template in that time. That is why we save all NOK options, for all items, in the `CHECKLIST_ANSWERS` table. With a simple join, we are able to recreate the same checklist answered by the user in that particular moment, taking into account what items or NOK options were active.

To solve the fast growing of the table, we came with 4 possible solutions, until now. Two of then assume we will not change what we save in the `CHECKLIST_ANSWERS` table, we would continue saving all NOK options, selected or not. The other two are considering that we change the implementation and instead of saving every NOK option and pointing out if the user has select this option or not, we would save **only** the selected options. So if the item is OK, would be no entries for this item in the table.

**Solutions keeping the same logic in `CHECKLIST_ANSWERS`:**

1 - Break the current `CHECKLIST_ANSWERS` table in two other tables

We could break the current `CHECKLIST_ANSWERS` table in two: `CHECKLIST_ANSWERS_SELECTED` and `CHECKLIST_ANSWERS_NOT_SELECTED`. This solution is easy to implement but the benefit is not so great. Most of the answered checklists have more than 90% of its NOK options not selected, so the `CHECKLIST_ANSWERS_NOT_SELECTED` table would continue to have a fast growth.
2 - Create specific tables by periods

The idea behind this approach is that we break the `CHECKLIST_ANSWERS` table by a period of time. So we could have a table by year, or month. To make SELECTs easy we could encapsulate the creation of an answered checklist inside a view (or function) to verify the checklist date and get data from the right table.

**Solutions changing the `CHECKLIST_ANSWERS` table to save only the selected NOK options:**

1 - Keep track of checklist template editions

Every time a checklist template is edited, we could save the state of every item and NOK option (if it was OK or not is enough). So, when we need to recreate a checklist we would need to verify what items and NOK options were active when the checklist was answered. Comparing the checklist date with the checklist template history. Besides the complexity this could add, we could encapsulate this verification inside a view (or function).

2 - Create another checklist template when every edition is made

Instead of keep track of what items and NOK options were (de)activated in every checklist template edition, we could simply create a new checklist template with new items and new NOK options. We doesn't like this solution because items or NOK options could change IDs frequently (even if the item text remains the same), so would be hard to create reports pointing out the most selected NOK, for example, because we would need to consider all different IDs of a NOK option. The checklist template itself could change its unique ID but that is easy to mitigate by simply creating a high level checklist template. So this high level template could only have a low level template active at a time. Anyway, we don't think the benefits of that approach justify its problems.

Now we are confused about what path to take. If we do refactor the table to only save the selected NOK options for a checklist (if the item is OK would be no entry for this item in the table) we lose the easy way to recreate an answered checklist already considering active items and NOK options. Is with worth it?

We could, as well, combine solutions from different categories, so another possible approach is:  Break the current `CHECKLIST_ANSWERS` table in two other tables
 **AND** Keep track of checklist template editions.

What would be the best way to deal with this fast growing table? Maybe some other techniques that we missed?

Comment: Its not really a solution, but what about leaving the structure as is and just archive old records to another set of tables or database even. That would allow you to report on old data whilst keeping your current tables a reasonable size..

Comment: But that would bring all the complexity to combine multiple tables or databases to generate a report of a big range. If we break in different tables, this must not be know by the client, he should still use the same tool to generate the report for old or new data. Or both.

Comment: it would increase the complexity of the queries you need to run to generate the reports, I don't know what tools the client uses or if you are able to modify them. but if you can i think you could implement the archive system without the client noticing.

Comment: In my opinion huge questions are difficult to get an answer, even with a bounty. I would propose that you cut it to one third.

Answer (score 0):

Use some database that is schemaless such as MongoDB for this .Your list of checks can grow or change frequently in the future.Its not advisable to add more colums in tables everytime you add a new cheklist item instead keep the schema flexible by using No-sql solutions.